# PGADMIN4 with DJANGO on google cloud 404 error

Tags: django, pgadmin-4

ok I can see the files. I can use the database. Apparently its running:

```
(myprojectenv) michael@contra:~/myproject$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2022-01-16 23:51:55 UTC; 2 days ago
 Main PID: 22981 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 613)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
```

However, when I go to contra.nz/pgadmin4 Django takes over and is looking for a page. How do I access PGADMIN4 without uninstalling DJANGO :(

Comment: May be Change the port for Django, so that it will not go to default port ?

Comment: Thanks @AdityaToshniwal but I found the isssue while reinstalling a tonne of things. 

Its not domain/admin 
Its domain/admin/ 

I feel stupid. but that's the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this answer isn't written anywhere.

For a 404 issue when trying to get to your django admin, it may be as simple as your missing the / at the end.

I.E

[www.domain.com/admin](http://www.domain.com/admin) will not work, it does even tell you in the error file.

you need to go to [www.domain.com/admin/](http://www.domain.com/admin/)

:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).